# Decrypt SQL Server encrypted data from .net

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, cryptography

Is it possible to decrypt the EncryptByCert-encrypted data that is stored in a SQL Server column from within .net?

I want to use [EncryptByCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188061(v=SQL.90).aspx) in a stored procedure to store a value RSA-encrpyted in a column. Then a client application will connect to SQL Server and request the encoded data and then needs to decode with the private key of the certificate. Is this possible?

I don't have a profound knowledge of encryption. That's why I ask this question. Maybe there is a good example for doing this?

Comment: I'm quite sure that this decryption is possible, but I didn't find which format is used by EncryptByCert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server encrypts the data to a sequence of bytes and returns this as the result. There **is no container format used**. Therefore, It can directly be decrypted by the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. Important to remark here is, that SQL Server uses PKCS #1 V1.5 padding (at least SQL Server 2005).

**One thing to notice:**
SQL server returns the encrypted result in reverse order as it is desired from `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. Therefore the byte sequence has to be reversed before decrypting it with `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt`.