# Decrypting encrypted SQL data using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I was looking for some solution you can use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to decrypt encrypted data stored in MS SQL Server. Is it possible to encrypt data using `ENCRYPTBYCERT` in SQL Server, then decrypt it in C#?

I found this question, [Decrypt SQL Server encrypted data from .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917692/decrypt-sql-server-encrypted-data-from-net) and tried it but I was unsuccessful.  I'm always receiving an error message `Bad key.` from `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt` function.

Any code or clue on how to implement this?